# $SU(2)$ acts transitively on $\mathbb{CP}^1$

Tags: group-theory, projective-geometry, group-actions, projective-space, linear-groups

How can one proof rigorously that the action of $SU(2)$ on $\mathbb{CP}^1$, where $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is the complex projective space, is transitive? i.e., that for any $u, v \in \mathbb{CP}^1$, there exists an $A \in SU(2)$ such that $A(u)=v$.

I can't seem to formulate a proof; other than that the statement is obvious?

Comment: If you want to prove the statement in Jose's answer, try to show that for any norm one vector v, you can build a matrix in SU with that vector as the first column. This matrix will send the standard basis vector e1 to v.  Check here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_unitary_group for a helpful explicit description of the matrices in SU(2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows from the fact that, given any two vectors $v$ and $w$ in $\mathbb{C}^2$ with $\|v\|=\|w\|=1$, there is some $g\in SU(2)$ such that $g.u=v$.

Comment: This was my thought, it just seemed a bit rough. Thanks for the answer!